# Load mongo driver on Xampp

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am using `XAMPP` portable and I have placed the `php_mongo.dll` in the `xampp/php/ext/` directory. My `php.ini` file is `extension=php_mongo.dll` but when I restart the xampp, it gives me the following alerts

[image]
[image]

Comment: you know, you might rather use [MAMP for windows](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp_windows.html). It's less buggy.

Comment: I prefer `xampp` as it is portable and I don't have to carry my machine with me all the time

Comment: what do you mean? how is mamp less portable? aren't they both development environment residing in a directory? In any event, it was just a suggestion as this seems like configuration problem and MAMP usually runs out of the box and comes bundled with many extensions, good luck with that